# Angular ng-click with call to a controller function not working

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass a variable to another controller. I have the following code which is related to the ListCtrl :

```
<a href="#items" data-router="article" ng-click="changeListName('metro')">
```

The link is going to another controller, ItemCtrl.

I want to pass a variable to the ItemCtrl. I thought of using a service called SharedProperties :

```
service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var list_name = '';

    return {
        getListName: function() {
            return list_name;
        },
        setListName: function(name) {
            list_name = name;
        }
    };
});
```

When the link is clicked, I call an angular click event to trigger the following function :

```
$scope.changeListName = function(name) {
    sharedProperties.setListName(name);
};
```

However, the ng-click does not seem to change the value of my shared property...

**UPDATE**

I put an alert inside the function triggered by ng-click and the alert is triggered, as it should be.

However, when I write my function like this :

```
$scope.changeListName = function(name) {
    sharedProperties.setListName(name);
};
```

It doesn't work... it looks like 'sharedProperties.setListName(name);' is not executed...

If I put it outside the function with a dummy name (eg. metro), it works..

**UPDATE 3**

I tried multiple things and I am pretty confident that the problem is with this function :

```
$scope.changeListName = function(list_name) {
    sharedProperties.setListName(list_name);
};
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You should probably use the [ngHref](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref) directive along with the ngClick:

```
 <a ng-href='#here' ng-click='go()' >click me</a>
```

Here is an example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/FSH0tP0YBFeGwjIhKBSx?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    {{msg}}
    <a ng-href='#here' ng-click='go()' >click me</a>
    <div style='height:1000px'>

      <a id='here'></a>

    </div>
     <h1>here</h1>
  </body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.go = function() {

    $scope.msg = 'clicked';
  }
});
```

I don't know if this will work with the library you are using but it will at least let you link and use the ngClick function.

** Update **

Here is a demo of the set and get working fine with a service.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FSH0tP0YBFeGwjIhKBSx?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.go = function(item) {
    sharedProperties.setListName(item);


  }

  $scope.getItem = function() {

    $scope.msg = sharedProperties.getListName();
  }
});

app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var list_name = '';

    return {

        getListName: function() {
            return list_name;
        },
        setListName: function(name) {
            list_name = name;
        }
    };


});
```

*** Edit ***

Please review https://github.com/centralway/lungo-angular-bridge which talks about how to use lungo and angular.  Also note that if your page is completely reloading when browsing to another link, you will need to persist your shared properties into localstorage and/or a cookie.

Comment: It looks like with both `ng-ref` and `href`, `ng-click` is triggered and fires my function. I updated my answer to better reflect my problem.

Comment: Are you asking a separate question now?

Comment: I modified my plunker with your service and it works fine.  I suspect you have some other issue going on.  You'll see the text of the Get form service link update with the value from the service.

Comment: I see it works fine in jsfiddle. Do you have any idea why it would not work in my app?

Comment: I found the source of the error. It comes from my second controller. the sharedProperties.getListName() method return an empty string, although the first controller did set the string to 'metro' in my example. I reproduced the behaviour here http://plnkr.co/edit/FSH0tP0YBFeGwjIhKBSx?p=preview

Comment: Wrong link in the previous post. This is the good one : http://plnkr.co/edit/dvAtg9d1ZG4AP4ZjJCcY

Comment: I don't understand your specific issue.  Are you opening index.html, calling setListName and then browsing to home.hmtml?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32897/discussion-between-lucuma-and-justin-d)

Answer (score 6):

Use alias when defining Controller in your angular configuration. For example:
NOTE: I'm using TypeScript here

Just take note of the Controller, it has an alias of homeCtrl.

```
module MongoAngular {
    var app = angular.module('mongoAngular', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute','restangular']);

    app.config([
        '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) => {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/Home', {
                    templateUrl: '/PartialViews/Home/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController as homeCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
        }])
        .config(['RestangularProvider', (restangularProvider: restangular.IProvider) => {
        restangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api');
    }]);
}
```

And here's the way to use it...

```
ng-click="homeCtrl.addCustomer(customer)"
```

Try it.. It might work for you as it worked for me... ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess you aren't getting errors or you would've mentioned them.  If that's the case, try removing the `href` attribute value so the page doesn't navigate away before your code is executed.  In Angular it's perfectly acceptable to leave `href` attributes blank.

```
<a href="" data-router="article" ng-click="changeListName('metro')">
```

Also I don't know what `data-router` is doing but if you still aren't getting the proper result, that could be why.

Comment: Data-router is for Lungo js. It has its own routing system. I can't remove the  href because then lungo won't know where to route...