# Angular Ng-click function does not work in button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, long-click

I want to navigate from one page to another page when I'm click the 'Sorgula' button. I wrote ng-click function and add controller but doesn't work.

```
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use $state.go use for navigate to another state.Dont forget to inject '$state' in controller   eg:- $state.go("Tab1.Main");

Comment: yap, use $state.go(path)

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for ngClick it requres expression to execute as mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Instead of expression you are providing controller's action so You should probably use the ngHref directive along with the ngClick:

This solution is already provided at following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457790/2871356)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $state.go use for navigate to another state.Dont forget to inject '$state' in controller eg:- $state.go("Tab1.Main");

Answer (score 1):

Remove the href="" where you have use ng-click to navigate to another route

in your case I mark it in red circle.

[image]

Then in your go function add code like below

```js
$scope.go = function(path) {
  $location.path(path);
}
```